# while submitting the form at preview page the form get submitted but at the time of submission form disappear

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my code for multistepform. Where I have implemented a multistep form functionality so here everything is going fine only the issue is In this form I have a preview page at final step so there while I am clicking on submit button at that time the form is disappearing and buttons are moving top. So If anyone can help me please.

```html
<form id="regForm" action="">
<h1>Register:</h1>
<!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
<div class="tab">Name:
    <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''" id="fname" name="fname"</p>
    <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''" id="lname" name="lname"</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">Contact Info:
    <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''" id="email" name="email"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''"  id="phone" name="phone"></p></div>
    <div class="tab">Birthday:
    <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''" id="dd" name="dd"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''" id="nn" name="nn"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''" id="yyyy" name="yyyy"></p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="tab">Review:
    
    <p><div id="review_fname" name="review_fname"></div></p>
    <p><div  id="review_lname" name="review_lname"></div></p>
    
    <p><div  id="review_email" name="review_email"></div></p>
    <p><div  id="review_phone" name="review_phone"></div></p>
    
    <p><div        id="review_dd" name="review_dd"></div></p>
    <p><div        id="review_nn" name="review_nn"></div></p>
    <p><div     id="review_yyyy" name="review_yyyy"></div></p>
    
    </div>
    
    <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
    <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
    <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    </div>
    </form>
    
    
    <script>
    var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
    showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab
    
    function showTab(n) {
    // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    x[n].style.display = "block";
    //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
    if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
    } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
    } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
    }
    //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
    fixStepIndicator(n)
    }
    
    function nextPrev(n) {
    // This function will figure out which tab to display
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
    if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
    // Hide the current tab:
    x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
    // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
    
    
    if(currentTab == x.length-2) {
    
    document.getElementById("review_fname").innerHTML = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    document.getElementById("review_lname").innerHTML = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    
    document.getElementById("review_email").innerHTML = document.getElementById("email").value;
    document.getElementById("review_phone").innerHTML = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    
    document.getElementById("review_dd").innerHTML = document.getElementById("dd").value;
    document.getElementById("review_nn").innerHTML = document.getElementById("nn").value;
    document.getElementById("review_yyyy").innerHTML = document.getElementById("yyyy").value; 
    
    
    }
    
    currentTab = currentTab + n;
    
    // if you have reached the end of the form...
    if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
    }
    
    // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
    showTab(currentTab);
    
    }
    
    
    
    function validateForm() {
    // This function deals with validation of the form fields
    var x, y, i, valid = true;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
    // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
    // add an "invalid" class to the field:
    y[i].className += " invalid";
    // and set the current valid status to false
    valid = false;
    }
    }
    // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
    if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
    }
    return valid; // return the valid status
    }
    
    function fixStepIndicator(n) {
    // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
    var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
    x[n].className += " active";
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: how many steps are they? ,  please show to complete Html markup.

Comment: I have updated the code. Will you please have a look and let me know why i am facing the problem

Comment: do you want to keep the preview after the submission?

Comment: after submission i dont want keep the preview. But at the time of submission form should not disappear

Comment: Try the one I posted in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, you needed to add `display:none` to each Tab except the first one

```html
<form id="regForm" action="">
<h1>Register:</h1>
<!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
<div class="tab">Name:
    <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''" id="fname" name="fname"</p>
    <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''" id="lname" name="lname"</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab" style="display: none;">Contact Info:
    <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''" id="email" name="email"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''"  id="phone" name="phone"></p></div>
    <div class="tab" style="display: none;">Birthday:
    <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''" id="dd" name="dd"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''" id="nn" name="nn"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''" id="yyyy" name="yyyy"></p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="tab" style="display: none;">Review:
    
    <p><div id="review_fname" name="review_fname"></div></p>
    <p><div  id="review_lname" name="review_lname"></div></p>
    
    <p><div  id="review_email" name="review_email"></div></p>
    <p><div  id="review_phone" name="review_phone"></div></p>
    
    <p><div        id="review_dd" name="review_dd"></div></p>
    <p><div        id="review_nn" name="review_nn"></div></p>
    <p><div     id="review_yyyy" name="review_yyyy"></div></p>
    
    </div>
    
    <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
    <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
    <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    </div>
    </form>
    
    
    <script>
    var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
    showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab
    
    function showTab(n) {
    // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    x[n].style.display = "block";
    //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
    if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
    } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
    } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
    }
    //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
    fixStepIndicator(n)
    }
    
    function nextPrev(n) {
    // This function will figure out which tab to display
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
    if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
    // Hide the current tab:
    x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
    // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
    
    
    if(currentTab == x.length-2) {
    
    document.getElementById("review_fname").innerHTML = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    document.getElementById("review_lname").innerHTML = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    
    document.getElementById("review_email").innerHTML = document.getElementById("email").value;
    document.getElementById("review_phone").innerHTML = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    
    document.getElementById("review_dd").innerHTML = document.getElementById("dd").value;
    document.getElementById("review_nn").innerHTML = document.getElementById("nn").value;
    document.getElementById("review_yyyy").innerHTML = document.getElementById("yyyy").value; 
    
    
    }
    
    currentTab = currentTab + n;
    
    // if you have reached the end of the form...
    if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
    }
    
    // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
    showTab(currentTab);
    
    }
    
    
    
    function validateForm() {
    // This function deals with validation of the form fields
    var x, y, i, valid = true;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
    // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
    // add an "invalid" class to the field:
    y[i].className += " invalid";
    // and set the current valid status to false
    valid = false;
    }
    }
    // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
    if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
    }
    return valid; // return the valid status
    }
    
    function fixStepIndicator(n) {
    // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
    var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
    x[n].className += " active";
    }
    </script>
```